# SQL Server Job Cannot Run SSIS Package Error 0xC00160AE Cluster Environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis

I have a 2 machine SQL Cluster and a separate SSIS/SSRS Server. I'm running SQL Server 2014 and Integration Services 12. I'm getting Error `0xC00160AE` when trying to run a job from my SQL cluster that executes a package from SSIS on the separate server.

I followed the directions on the below link and gave permissions to `NNU\srv_sql` to run the SSIS service but I am continuing to get this error. I'm at a loss of what steps I need to take next.

Supporting Link: [SISS error `0xc00160ae` access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885641/ssis-error-0xc00160ae-access-is-denied) from SO

Error Message:

> **Executed as user:** `NNU\srv_sql`. 
>  Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute
>   Package Utility 
>  Version 12.0.4100.1 for 64-bit 
>  Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Could not load package "`\File System\ImpData`" because of error
>   `0xC00160AE`.
>
> **Description:** Connecting to the Integration Services
>   service on the computer "`ACSLCRSP010`" failed with the following error:
>   "**Access is denied.**"
>
> By default `<c/>` only administrators have access
>   to the Integration Services service. On Windows Vista and later `<c/>`
>   the process must be running with administrative privileges in order to
>   connect to the Integration Services service. See the help topic for
>   information on how to configure access to the service.
>
> **Source:**
> Started:  2:40:08 PM  
> Finished: 2:40:08 PM
>   Elapsed:  0.047 seconds.
>
> The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.